# how is https recognised?

Tags: http, browser, https, server

I don't see any mention about secure connection in http headers (it's basically the same for http/1.1, http/2 and https). How does server know that we want a secure connection?

As I understand https is just plain old http encrypted by TLS 'tool' (which is still done in userland, that is in the browser) before it gets down into TCP connection.

It seems that the only recognition is that in secure connection immediately after TCP handshake goes TLS client hello message. If server is set to support secure connections on a given socket it errors when it doesn't see that message. And when a connection is insecure, the server errors because it doesn't know how to handle a client hello.

Is this correct?

Comment: HTTP uses port 80, HTTPS uses 443.

Comment: @tkausl those are default ports but I can set any other port and even listen for https at port 80

Comment: But then you can't connect to port 80 using HTTP. HTTP or HTTPS simply isn't recognized automatically. Either you specify it beforehand or the connection will simply fail.

Comment: @tkausl yes of course, but what I'm trying to say is port numbers doesn't matter. Default ports are only a commonly used convention and not something that differentiates http from https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS is either on or off for a given port number.  When the server is configured to listen on a given port you configure it to either listen for HTTPS or HTTP (how varies from server to server).  If the server is configured to listen for HTTPS connections then then when something connects it immediately starts the encryption process and the connection will fail if the other side isn't also expecting encryption.

When a browser connects to a server it decides whether to speak HTTP or HTTPS based on the schema of the URL the user typed in.  If they typed https:// then it'll make an encrypted connection to the server on the specified port (or 443 if unspecified).  If the server is not expecting an encrypted connection on that port, the connection fails.

If the user types http:// then the browser speaks unencrypted http on the specified port (or 80 if unspecified).  Again, if the server is expecting the traffic to be encrypted then the connection fails.

Only if the two sides have matching expectations will the connection succeed.

It is theoretically possible to use the [HTTP Upgrade header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header) to start a plain unencrypted HTTP connection then enable encryption, similar to STARTTLS in other protocols.  As far as I am aware such functionality is rarely if ever used though.  Almost always encryption is enabled from the very beginning by using a specific encrypted traffic port number.